# How to show diff between curl outputs

Tags: bash, curl

i'm using this simple bash script to pull prices from a cryptourrency exchange.

```
Bid=$(curl -w "\n" --silent https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-nanas | cut -c 46-55)
Ask=$(curl -w "\n" --silent https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-nanas | cut -c 63-72)
Last=$(curl -w "\n" --silent https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-nanas | cut -c 81-90)

while true;
do echo `date` Bid:$Bid, Ask:$Ask, Last:$Last;
sleep 5;
done
```

Now i was wondering is there any way i could compare one curl output to the one before so that i could add colors in case of a price increase/decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you're only running the command once (for each variable) outside the loop then printing the same values every time.  Here's a sample script that will do a request inside the loop, then check if the bid has gone up or down and add colors as appropriate.  You can extend this to the other fields if it suits your purpose:

```
increase='\033[0;31m' # red
decrease='\033[0;32m' # green
none='\033[0m' # to clear the color code

while /bin/true; do
    results=$(curl -w "\n" --silent https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-nanas)

    cur_bid=$(echo $results | cut -c 46-55)
    cur_ask=$(echo $results | cut -c 63-72)
    cur_last=$(echo $results | cut -c 81-90)

    if [[ -z $old_bid ]]; then
        bid_out=$cur_bid
    else
        if (( $(bc <<< "$cur_bid > $old_bid" ) == 1 )); then
            bid_out="${increase}${cur_bid}${none}"
        elif (( $(bc <<< "$cur_bid < $old_bid" ) == 1 )); then
            bid_out="${decrease}${cur_bid}${none}"
        else
            bid_out=$cur_bid
        fi
    fi

    printf "$(date) Bid:$bid_out ...\n"

    old_bid=$cur_bid
    sleep 5
done
```

I just used your code for grabbing the right parts of the curl results, though there may be a more reliable way than grabbing specific sets of characters.

Comment: No, not really, using cut is the best way i found (i used sed before but that was worse).
Thanks a lot for the answer!